# apply function to each column of a matrix (Vectorizing)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

What is fastest way of applying function on each column of a matrix without looping through it?

The function I am using is `pwelch` but the concept should be the same for any function.
Currently I am looping though my matrix as such.

```
 X = ones(5);
    for i = 1:5 % length of the number of columns
    result = somefunction(X(:,i))
    end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say

> the concept should be the same for any function

Actually that's not the case. Depending on the function, the code that calls it can be made vectorized or not. It depends on how the function is written internally. From outside the function there's nothing you can do to make it vectorized. Vectorization is done *within the function*, not from the outside.

If the function *is* vectorized, you simply call it with a matrix, and the function works on each column. For example, that's what `sum` does.

In the case of `pwelch`, you are lucky: according to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) (emphasis added),

> `Pxx = pwelch(X)` returns the Power Spectral Density (PSD) estimate, `Pxx`, ...
>
> *When `X` is a matrix, the PSD is
>       computed independently for each column and stored in the corresponding
>       column of `Pxx`*.

So `pwelch` *is* a vectorized function.

Comment: I missed that big time. Was attacking the problem form the wrong side. Thanks!