# Apply different functions to columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have a matrix, for example, "A", with size 5 * n, where "n" is a large number. I want to apply functions to the columns of "A", is `for` loop the best solution?

To be specific, assume

```
A = randn(5, 10000);
B = randn(5, 5000);
ix = cell(1, 10000);
for i =1:10000
    n = poissrnd(5);
    ix{i} = datasample(1:5000, n, 'replace', false);
end
```

and I want to do the following:

```
for i = 1:10000
    A(:, i) = B(:, ix{i}) * B(:, ix{i})' * A(:,i);
end
```

The function in this example is just `B(:, ix{i}) * B(:, ix{i})'` and "ix" is a cell of vectors which are indices, for example, "ix{i}" could be `[1, 3, 11, 20]`.

Comment: what is `ix_1`, `ix_i`, ... ? please give a complete example.

Comment: Also tell us what the function is. The answer highly depends on that. See for example [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29776742/2586922)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I guess the function is already given, A = B*B'*A

Comment: yeah what is in ix? Indices?

Comment: @krisdestruction: Yes , ix is a cell of indices, I edited the question to make things clear.

Comment: @m.s.: Just as Luis said, the function is B*B'.

Comment: is `ix_i` the same for every `i`? You should give a full working example using the loop.

Comment: @llcc What are the indices? Please exemplify with some example values.

Comment: Maybe now is understandable.